# PDF file download in Firefox results in "Error: not well-formed Line: 1, Column: 9 Source Code: %PDF-1.4"

Tags: jsf, download, omnifaces

I have a JSF web project where I generate output in Jasper Reports 5.0.
I am trying to send the output back to the browser. I have used both Omnifaces (1.2) and Primefaces 3.4.2 (showcase) examples.

When checking the error log in Firefox, it says

> Timestamp: 12/10/12 9:40:39 PM Error: not well-formed Line: 1, Column:
>   9 Source Code: %PDF-1.4

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

This error is recognizable as a XML parsing error during processing of the HTTP response in the client side. This in turn indicates that the response is implicitly treated as XML. This in turn indicates that you were actually sending an ajax request which by default assumes every response as XML.

It is not possible to download files by ajax. Ajax requests are processed by JavaScript, which has due to security reasons no facilities to programmatically trigger a *Save As* dialogue with aribitrary content.

Remove the `<f:ajax>` from the command link/button, or in case of PrimeFaces, add `ajax="false"` to the command link/button.

Comment: You are my f*ing hero! Adding ajax="false" worked like a charm to solve "file parse error". (y)